# QuerySelectorAll is undefined when passed as a variable into an array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write the `setwidth()` function to resize all elements in a given variable (time/city/event) to the width of the broadest element in the set. However the function throws an undefined on the line:

```
selectorWidth = selectorArray[0].offsetWidth;
```

Any idea how to fix this code?

```
var time = document.querySelectorAll('.eventinstance > time'),
        city = document.querySelectorAll('.eventinstance > .location'),
        event = document.querySelectorAll('.eventname');

    function setwidth(selector) {
        var selectorArray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < selector.length; i++) {
                selectorArray.push(selector[i]);
            }
        var maxWidth = 0,
            selectorWidth = selectorArray[0].offsetWidth;
        maxWidth = selectorWidth;
        for (var i = 1; i < selector.length; i++) {
            maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, selectorArray[i].offsetWidth);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < selector.length; i++) {
            selector[i].setAttribute("style", "width:"+maxWidth+"px");
        }
    }


    function addLoadEvent(func,what) {
        var oldonload = window.onload;
        if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
            window.onload = func;
        } else {
            window.onload = function () {
                if (oldonload) {
                    oldonload();
                }
                func(what);
            }
        }
    }
    addLoadEvent(setwidth,time);
    addLoadEvent(setwidth,city);
    addLoadEvent(setwidth,event);
```

Comment: Have you tried to verify therere's at least one item in there?

Comment: Add a [minimal and working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please. Maybe you find the problem by just creating the example and save you and us a lot of time ;-) Try to use the snippet tool to add HTML and JavaScript that reproduce this problem.

Comment: Note that your selection will occur well before the event occurs, since you're setting your variables at the top...